# Error : Could not find class to initialize base class in c++

Tags: c++

sub_cktmgr  is getting dreived from CpGenricManger and  CpGenricManger from CPmanager.
Please find the hierarchy below.

```
//CPManager COnstructor

cpManager();
cpManager(const cpManagerResource &m);
cpManager(cpObjectNotify *p);
cpManager(const cpManagerResource &m, cpObjectNotify *p);



//CpGenricManger Constructor

 class cpGenericMgr: public cpManager{
 public:

 cpGenericMgr(const std::string& serviceName);

cpGenericMgr(const cpManagerResource &m,const std::string& serviceName);
cpGenericMgr(cpObjectNotify *p,const std::string& serviceName);
cpGenericMgr(const cpManagerResource &m,cpObjectNotify *p,
    const std::string& serviceName);

// Destructor

virtual ~cpGenericMgr();
 }


//Sb_cktmgr
SB_CktMgr::SB_CktMgr(const cpManagerResource &m, const String& svcName) :
cpGenericMgr(m, svcName){
cpUdata dsm(USER_DATA);
this->userData(dsm);
```

Even though the hierachy is correct we are still getting the following error.Can some one please suggest.

```
      Error: Could not find cpGenericMgr::cpGenericMgr(const cpManagerResource, const String) to initialize base class.
```

Comment: Is that the exact compiler error message?

Comment: The error you put in your answer is almost certainly not the exact error you're getting. Additionally, the error you *are* getting almost certainly tells you what the problem is.

Comment: And now that you've fixed the question to represent what the error actually states: it's telling you that there is no `cpGenericMgr` constructor that takes `String`. That's right, there isn't. All `cpGenericMgr` constructors take `std::string`. That's a different type.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have defined a constructor:

```
cpGenericMgr::cpGenericMgr(const cpManagerResource&, const String&)
```

only

```
cpGenericMgr::cpGenericMgr(const cpManagerResource&, const std::string&)
```

is defined.

Either cast `String` to `std::string` or define a constructor with `const String&`

Comment: cpGenericMgr(const cpManagerResource &m,const std::string& serviceName); is already declared and defined ,why compiler is not bale to find that one?

Comment: @kara Because the parameter you are passing is not of type `std::string` but of type `String`. `std::string` != `String`